# Unable to import packages in Jupyter Notebook, python sys.executable from jupyter notebook is different than the one from terminal

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pip, anaconda, virtual-environment

I have created a conda environment (which contains a pip package named pyjokes).
However, when I create a Jupyter notebook and choose that environment, I am unable to import the package I had added with pip (whereas in the Anaconda prompt terminal, I am able to import that package just fine).
Furthermore, I checked `sys.executable` and `sys.version` in the jupyter Notebook vs. the ones I get from the Terminal, and they are different.

**From Jupyter Notebook**:

```
sys.executable: 
C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\python.exe
sys.version: 
3.10.9 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Mar  1 2023, 18:18:15) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

import pyjokes
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 1
----> 1 import pyjokes

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyjokes'
```

**From Terminal**:

```
(my_env) C:\Users\my_user_name>python
Python 3.8.1 (default, Mar  2 2020, 13:06:26) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Users\\my_user_name\\.conda\\envs\\my_env\\python.exe'
>>> sys.version
'3.8.1 (default, Mar  2 2020, 13:06:26) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]'
>>> import pyjokes
>>>
```

That shows me that Jupyter notebook and the environment I am using in the terminal are pointing to two different versions of python and that is why I am unable to import my package. Note that I had encountered this same problem in the past, and the solution had been to install `nb_conda` in the terminal within my environment, i.e., I used to be able to just execute this command:
`conda install nb_conda` , and that would do the trick. Meaning, afterwards, I would kickoff jupyter notebook with my environment, and check again and now the sys.executable in both jupyter and terminal would be the same.
Unfortunately, this is not working any more.

I checked other people answers on this issue, and some people suggested manually editing the `kernel.json` file.
I have checked my system, and I have encountered two kernel.json files.

**(1)One is located here:** `C:\Users\my_user_name\.conda\envs\my_env\share\jupyter\kernels\python3\kernel.json`

with content:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "C:/Users/my_user_name/.conda/envs/my_env\\python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3 (ipykernel)",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}
```

**(2)The other is here:** `C:\Users\my_user_name\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\my_env\kernel.json`

with content:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "my_env",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}
```

But it is not clear to me exactly which file I should modify and which part - or if I should be modifying both. I did try to modify the kernel.json file **(2)**, and I replaced `"C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\python.exe"` with `"C:/Users/my_user_name/.conda/envs/my_env\\python.exe"`, but that did not work, after doing that and launching jupyter notebook, the kernel would just die. And so I reverted file **(2)** back to its original form.

Right now, I am really not sure what else I can try. Any tips on how to solve this would be very appreciated.

Comment: If you'd rather not struggle further with trying to connect the right things, and / or you want something else to try ... In your notebook running in the environment where you want to work, make a new cell and run `%conda install -c conda-forge pyjokes`. After it completes, restart the kernel and try the import. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magic install commands to insure installation in the proper environment when run inside the notebook.

Comment: I find this article very helpful https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/